# Is there a way to wait for one stream's data before listening to another stream that is dependent on the first

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stacked, flutter-streambuilder

I rely on more than one stream for the data in my app. In this specific situation I listen to the first stream which is dependent on User UID (Firebase Auth) which I already have. But the 2nd stream needs something returned from the 1st stream.

Extra Context: I am using the MultipleStreamViewModel as part of the stacked package (flutter).

```
class HomeViewModel extends MultipleStreamViewModel{

  @override
  Map<String, StreamData> get streamsMap => {
        _userDataStream: StreamData<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(

           //This stream contain the groupID needed
          _userService.getUserData(uid: uid),), //Stream


        _userGroupsStream: StreamData<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(

          //This Stream requires the groupID from the previous stream.
          _userService.getGroupData(groupID groupID),), //Stream

     }
}
```

I was hoping that the order I listed the streams would allow for the one before to get the information that the following one required, but that did not work.